# Prove that $\frac{du}{dt}=\delta(t)$ where $u(t)$ is Unit step function, $\delta(t)$ is impulse function

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals

I want to prove that $$\frac{du}{dt}=\delta(t)$$
To do that I want to use the following:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t) * g^{(n)}(t)dt = (-1)^n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi^{(n)}(t)*g(t)dt$$
What I tried is to assign $u'(t)$ in $g'(t)$:

$$... = (-1)^n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi'(t)*u(t)dt$$

Notes:  $u(t)$ is Unit Step, $\delta(t)$ is impulse function, $g(t)$ is random function

I guess I need to use the unit step features but I dont know to continue.
Any suggestion are welcomed! thanks.

Comment: What the hell are $u(t), \delta(t), \Phi(t), g(t)$...??? How can you expect anyone to help you without giving any details and context...?

Comment: You right, forgot to mention that.

Comment: No $g(t)$ is not " a random function"... Actually what is most needed here is *your definition* of the Dirac $\delta$ (I guess that $u(t)=0$ if $t<0$ and $u(t)=1$ if $t\geqslant0$, maybe you could also confirm this). Until you provide one there is no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in the classical sense, that derivative doesn't exist. So what you're looking for a distributional derivative.

So let $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u'\phi dx=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u\phi' dx=-\int_0^{\infty}\phi' dx=-\phi\big|_0^{\infty}=\phi(0)$

That is, distributionally, $u'=\delta(x)$.

Comment: Why $\phi(0)$ is equal to $\delta(t)$?

Comment: By the way, $\phi(t)$ is a testing function right? you can tell me what are the features of this function? thanks, ( I am asking this because I understand from your answer that $\phi(0) = \delta(t)$ ).

Comment: $\delta$ isn't equal to $\phi(0)$, but $\delta$ acting on a test function $\phi$ will give you $\phi(0)$: $\langle \delta, \phi \rangle = \phi(0)$; this is more or less the definition of $\delta$.

Comment: So from view that $\delta$ with test function giving me $\phi(0)$ I can say that the inverse is that $\phi(0)$ will give $\delta$ ?

Comment: @OfirAttia how much math do you know? For instance, do phrases like Riesz Representation Theorem, Dual Space,  Linear Functional, Measure Space etc. make sense? I'll try to explain it more, depending on your level.